# How to parse xml using groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, jsoup, groovy-console

I'm new to groovy xml parsing. I'm trying to parse the below xml file

```
<font face=Tahoma size=2>
   Team,<br/><br/>  Please find below the test summary details for the 'Test' execution.<br/><br/><b><U>Transaction Summary Table:</U></b><br/><br/>
   <table border=1 CELLPADDING =3 style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12'>
      <tr>
         <b>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> TransactionName </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> AverageLatency </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> MinimumLatency </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> MaximumLatency </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> AverageElapsedTime </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> MinimumElapsedTime </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> MaximumElapsedTime </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> TotalCount </th>
            <th bgcolor=#C0C0C0> PassPercentage </th>
         </b>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1 /aumentum/</td>
         <td>
            <center>1648.0</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1240</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>2900</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1907.0</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1495</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>3140</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>45</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>100.0</center>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>T01_Aumentum_Home</td>
         <td>
            <center>6.0</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>10</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1956.0</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>1490</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>3806</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>213</center>
         </td>
         <td>
            <center>0.0</center>
         </td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
   </table>
   <br/><br/>Thanks,<br/>Performance Team.
</font>
<br/><br/>
```

Expected Result:

```
 [{
"transaction name":"1 /aumentum/", 
"AverageLatency ":"1648.0",
"Minimum latency":"1240",
"MaximumLatency ":"2900",
"AverageElapsedTime":"1907.0",
"MinimumElapsedTime":"1495",
"MaximumElapsedTime":"3140",
"TotalCount":"45",
"PassPercentage":"100.0"
},
{
"transaction name": "1 /aumentum/",
"AverageLatency ":"1648.0",
"Minimum latency":"1240",
"MaximumLatency ":"2900",
"AverageElapsedTime":"1907.0",
"MinimumElapsedTime":"1495",
"MaximumElapsedTime":"3140",
"TotalCount":"45",
"PassPercentage":"100.0"

}]
```

i have got the first children using values using `docParser.getElementsByTag("tr").first()`

Here is the error I get:

```
Exception thrown
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:519)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.child(Element.java:174)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element$child$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at CommonUtils.parseLRHTMLReport(jmeteragent.groovy:304)
    at CommonUtils$parseLRHTMLReport.call(Unknown Source)
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def transactiondetails12 = null
def iterator12 = 0
int count1 = 0
def violcounts = 0
def violations = null;

tmpElement = docParser.getElementsByTag("tr").first()
println tmpElement.children()
// tmpElement= tmpElement.child(0)
// println "#########tmpElement#########:" +tmpElement


for (element in tmpElement.children()) {
    if (iterator12 == 0) {
        // transactiondetails1 = "<table border=1 CELLPADDING =3 style='font-family:Tahoma;font-size:12'><tr><b><th bgcolor=#C0C0C0>"  +
        element.child(0).text().trim() + "</th><th bgcolor=#C0C0C0>" + element.child(2).text().trim() + "</th><th bgcolor=#C0C0C0>" +
                element.child(3).text().trim() + "</th><th bgcolor=#C0C0C0>" + element.child(4).text().trim() + "</th></b></tr>"
        iterator12 = 1;
        count1++;
        //  println "nqwlieufrh    2938ry    `9p23dhWCDNJ    p3fu89    Q2390RUD"+transactiondetails1
    } else {
        count1++;
        if (count1 <= 5) {

            //   println "iterator1iterator1iterator1iterator1"+iterator1++
            transactiondetails12 = transactiondetails12 + "<tr><td>" + element.child(0).text().trim() + "</td><td><center>" +
                    element.child(2).text().trim() + "</center></td><td><center>" +
                    element.child(3).text().trim() + "</center></td><td><center>" +
                    element.child(4).text().trim()
            println "transactiondetails12" + transactiondetails12
            //   println "3215463654156436212315465123011482145634217225445622341"+element.child(4).text().trim()
            String violation1 = element.child(1).text()
            // violation=Integer.valueOf(violation1)
            // violation=Integer.parseInt(violation1)

            //   if(violation1>=0)
            if (violation1.length() > 0) {
                violcounts++
            }


        }
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to map the `tmpElement.children()` values. Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you have provided uses [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library that is useful for HTML DOM manipulation. The solution to your problem is to use correct selectors to extract the data.

Consider following example:

```
def headers = docParser.select("tr > th").collect { it.text() }
def result = []

docParser.select("tr:has(td)").each { tr ->
    def obj = [:]
    tr.select("td").eachWithIndex { Element td, int i ->
        obj[headers[i]] = td.text()
    }
    result << obj
}

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(result))
```

- `docParser.select("tr > th").collect { it.text() }` collects table headers and stores them as an ordered `List<String>`
- `docParser.select("tr:has(td)")` selects all rows (excluding table header) with data
- `tr.select("td").eachWithIndex` iterates inside each row, collects the data and associates it with header by index `i`
- the last line displays desired output to console

Output:

```
[
    {
        "TransactionName": "1 /aumentum/",
        "AverageLatency": "1648.0",
        "MinimumLatency": "1240",
        "MaximumLatency": "2900",
        "AverageElapsedTime": "1907.0",
        "MinimumElapsedTime": "1495",
        "MaximumElapsedTime": "3140",
        "TotalCount": "45",
        "PassPercentage": "100.0"
    },
    {
        "TransactionName": "T01_Aumentum_Home",
        "AverageLatency": "6.0",
        "MinimumLatency": "1",
        "MaximumLatency": "10",
        "AverageElapsedTime": "1956.0",
        "MinimumElapsedTime": "1490",
        "MaximumElapsedTime": "3806",
        "TotalCount": "213",
        "PassPercentage": "0.0"
    }
]
```

And here you can find full Groovy script I've used for experimenting with your example: https://gist.github.com/wololock/651a536dff4e104ebba0eef69d4ac3ea

I hope it helps.